# Finding or calculating the stats on a tournament

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

This problem was bugging me for the last couple of weeks, but the solution I've reached so far doesn't seem good enough to aleviate the doubts I have.

**Problem Statement**: Build a table (query) that shows the followings columns (team name, number of matches, victories, defeats, draws, and score) the score of each team is calculated knowing that each victory gives 3 points and a draw gives one point, while defeats don't afect at all.

**Table Schemas:**

Table "*teams*":

| Column name | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | int |
| name | varchar(50) |

Table "*matches*":

| Column name | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | int |
| team_1 | int |
| team_2 | int |
| team_1_goals | int |
| team_2_goals | int |

**Sample Data:**

Table "*teams*":

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | CEARA |
| 2 | FORTALEZA |
| 3 | GUARANY DE SOBRAL |
| 4 | FLORESTA |

Table "*matches*":

| id | team_1 | team_2 | team_1_goals | team_2_goals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 1 | 0 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 3 | 4 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 1 |

**Expected Output**:

| name | matches | victories | defeats | draws | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CEARA | 3 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 7 |
| FORTALEZA | 3 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 7 |
| FLORESTA | 3 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 3 |
| GUARANY DE SOBRAL | 3 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 |

**What I've managed to do so far**:

```
SELECT
    t.name, 
    count(m.team_1) filter(WHERE t.id = m.team_1)
        + count(m.team_2) filter(WHERE t.id = m.team_2) "matches",
    count(m.team_1) filter(WHERE t.id = m.team_1 AND m.team_1_goals > m.team_2_goals)
        + count(m.team_2) filter(WHERE t.id = m.team_2 AND m.team_1_goals < m.team_2_goals) "victories",
    count(m.team_1) filter(WHERE t.id = m.team_1 AND m.team_1_goals < m.team_2_goals)
        + count(m.team_2) filter(WHERE t.id = m.team_2 AND m.team_1_goals > m.team_2_goals) "defeats",
    count(m.team_1) filter(WHERE t.id = m.team_1 AND m.team_1_goals = m.team_2_goals)
        + count(m.team_2) filter(WHERE t.id = m.team_2 AND m.team_1_goals = m.team_2_goals) "draws",
    ((count(m.team_1) filter(WHERE t.id = m.team_1 AND m.team_1_goals > m.team_2_goals)
        + count(m.team_2) filter(WHERE t.id = m.team_2 AND m.team_1_goals < m.team_2_goals))* 3) +
        count(m.team_1) filter(WHERE t.id = m.team_1 AND m.team_1_goals = m.team_2_goals)
        + count(m.team_2) filter(WHERE t.id = m.team_2 AND m.team_1_goals = m.team_2_goals) "score"
FROM
    teams t
JOIN matches m ON t.id IN (m.team_1, m.team_2)
GROUP BY t.name
ORDER BY "victories" DESC
```

which theoretically outputs the correct answer.

I've tried to make it by using fancy things like `CASE WHEN` or a bigger `JOIN` but with no good results. What I want to know is if there is a better way to do this query in terms of writing and performance in the server.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normalized the layout of the `matches` table to simplify things, but I assume that the structure of that table was given to you.  Please let me know if you have control over the structure of the `matches` table, and I can show you how to use `lead()` to determine the win/loss/draw status for each side of a match.

If you represent the point value as a table (or a CTE, common table expression, in this case), you can simplify the aggregations:

```
with norm_matches as (
  select id as match_id, team_1 as team_id, team_1_goals as goals, 
         case
           when team_1_goals > team_2_goals then 'W'
           when team_1_goals = team_2_goals then 'D'
           when team_1_goals < team_2_goals then 'L'
         end as outcome
    from matches
  union all
  select id as match_id, team_2 as team_id, team_2_goals as goals, 
         case
           when team_1_goals > team_2_goals then 'L'
           when team_1_goals = team_2_goals then 'D'
           when team_1_goals < team_2_goals then 'W'
         end as outcome
    from matches
), points (outcome, value) as (
  values ('W', 3), ('D', 1), ('L', 0)
)
select t.name, 
       count(1) as matches,
       count(1) filter (where m.outcome = 'W') as victories,
       count(1) filter (where m.outcome = 'L') as defeats,
       count(1) filter (where m.outcome = 'D') as draws,
       sum(p.value) as score
  from teams t
       join norm_matches m on m.team_id = t.id
       join points p on p.outcome = m.outcome
 group by t.name
 order by t.name
;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6ddda66e451688c10ab050b725cd216c)*

Answer (score 1):

One option is to

- unify the "*matches*" fields into "*team*" and "*goals*" twice (one for each team), while keeping trace of the wins (1 if team A won on team B, 0 for draws, -1 for lost match)
- apply a `LEFT JOIN` between "*teams*" table and the just-updated "*matches*" table
- use all needed aggregations in combination of CASE statements, as in the example below (`COALESCE` will convert any null value into zero).

```
WITH cte_matches AS (
    SELECT id, 
           team_1                                          AS team, 
           team_1_goals                                    AS goals, 
           CASE WHEN team_1_goals > team_2_goals THEN 1
                WHEN team_1_goals < team_2_goals THEN -1
                ELSE 0 END                                 AS has_won
    FROM matches
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, 
           team_2                                          AS team, 
           team_2_goals                                    AS goals, 
           CASE WHEN team_2_goals > team_1_goals THEN 1
                WHEN team_2_goals < team_1_goals THEN -1
                ELSE 0 END                                 AS has_won
    FROM matches
)
SELECT t.name, 
       COUNT(t.id)      AS matches,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN has_won =  1 THEN 1 END), 0) AS victories,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN has_won = -1 THEN 1 END), 0) AS defeats,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN has_won =  0 THEN 1 END), 0) AS draws,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN has_won =  1 THEN 3
                         WHEN has_won =  0 THEN 1 END), 0) AS score
FROM      teams       t
LEFT JOIN cte_matches m
       ON t.id = m.team
GROUP BY t.name
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gR2RzssaJYAX4duDe1Y1r4/0).